# Unable to access systemd --user due to DBus access permissions

Tags: fedora, systemd, d-bus

I'm trying to setup a service account using systemd units to manage the actual service + supporting code. However, it looks like the systemd user daemon isn't working properly.

```
$ systemctl --user
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Permission denied
```

**EDIT**: I've made some progress by ensuring I have an interactive shell (using su - instead of su to switch to the service account). This has helped, but it looks like my D-Bus woes aren't over:

```
$ systemctl --user
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to suss out what I need to do to make sure this user does have dbus access. Adding them to the dbus group has had little benefit.

```
$ groups
printing lp rpc dbus users chrony ipausers
```

I'm running Fedora Core 23

Comment: Is `pam_systemd` PAM module called when you are login as your service user? What is the UID of that service user?

Comment: It is, although a little research has determined that it behaves differently depending on how I login (su vs su - or direct ssh). Still doesn't work but I get a different error.

Comment: `su` is not a login mechanism.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423648/5132

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are mixing up two different concepts:

- The main systemd system instance is used to start system services under any system user;
- The user specific systemd instances are there for interactive user that wish to run session services.

System services do not get a user instance as they are managed by the system instance. In your case, I think you should write your unit as system units and have them managed directly by systemd PID 1.