# How to switch systemd user/shell on remote server without logging in again via ssh?

Tags: systemd, login, podman

This is a remote machine with SSH access and systemd.

I basically have this error when I try to run systemd user commands:

```
$ systemctl --user status
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

While [other answers suggest to just set or "fake" the requested variables](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121053/606016) IMHO, this is not a proper solution.

The problem is basically that I logged in as a one user (I use as a system admin) [and I did switch the user via `su`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615964/146739). As such, it's very much understandable systemd does not have a clue what user I'm running here…
So I understand it is confused.

Note while for systemd services [maybe using the system bus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616636/146739) is maybe the better idea altogether.

However, for experimenting with podman and especially `podman generate systemd` also wants a user-level session, maybe just having a *lingering* user (`loginctl enable-linger`) is a useful way.

---

Now the actual question: **How can I switch to the other user, so that systemd really knows that this user is now logged in?** I just want to "operate" as a different user (in a new shell). Just as if I would use `su`.

Note that I do not want to SSH into the server as another user. That requires additional SSH keys and other stuff that is just not necessary. I want to switch my user while being logged in (as a user that can run `sudo`, i.e. system admin).

### Tries

I've `sudo machinectl login`, but that is:

- inconvenient, as I need to type the username again in there (I cannot do `sudo machinectl login my-user`.
- a problem, as my user is a system user just for podman and I don't have a password set – so I cannot login with a password

I've found `machinectl shell`, which sounds exactly what I want to do, but I cannot get it to work.
I've tried `machinectl shell my-user` and `machinectl shell my-user@localhost`, but it always just tells me:

> Failed to get shell PTY: No machine 'localhost' known

Well… note that it also shows me I have no "machines" (whatever these are? Is not `localhost` one?):

```
$ machinectl list
No machines.
```

Answer (score 7):

Ahh, I nearly got it:

Note that for whatever reason the local "machine" (i.e. "localhost") for `machinectl` is called `:host`.

Also for whatever reason it hides it in `machinectl list`.
You need to run `machinectl list --all` to actually see it.

Now, given we know that, it's actually quite easy:
Just run this:

```
$ sudo machinectl shell my-user@.host
```

And there you are… in your new shell of `my-user`.
You can (somewhat) verify this if you check the environmental variables `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` that were there in my initial error.

Also note there is apparently another alternative syntax that does not require the knowledge of that "local" machine:

```
$ sudo machinectl shell --uid my-user
```

Actually, that's also mentioned at the end of the [`machinectl` man page in the examples section](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/machinectl.1.html#EXAMPLES).

Comment: Still couldn't make `machinectl login` works. I now use `machinectl shell` instead of `su` every time. No DBus error anymore.